# MS SQL - Standard edition - Asymmetric backup encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, database-backups

I need to solve a problem with safe backup of Microsoft sql server databases.
I got an idea, solve it by using encrypted backups.
The problem is, that I don't understand how Microsoft invented it.
I thought the following procedure would work.

Create an asymmetric key:

- a public key - which will encrypt the customer's database backup (on his servers)
- a private key - to decrypt the backup (on my servers)

The problem is that Microsoft requires the presence of a private key when using an asymmetric key (on customer SQL server). This breaks down the entire principle of secure backup.

I need nobody to have a private key - to get the backup. (Only me). But Microsoft needs me to upload it to SQL Server. This will cause anyone who gets to the server, gets a private key, to get the backup.

What am I doing wrong?
Or is the backup encryption with an asymmetric key available only in the enterprice editions?

Comment: As stated in the documentation [prerequistes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-encryption?view=sql-server-2017#Prerequisites): *"1. Create a Database Master Key for the master database: The database master key is a symmetric key that is used to protect the private keys of certificates and asymmetric keys that are present in the database. For more information, see SQL Server and Database Encryption Keys (Database Engine)."*

Comment: *"Create a certificate or asymmetric Key to use for backup encryption. For more information on creating a certificate, see CREATE CERTIFICATE (Transact-SQL). For more information on creating an asymmetric key, see CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY (Transact-SQL)."* If you don't want people accessing the keys on the server, then they shouldn't have `sysadmin` access.

Comment: When I use an asymmetric key and want to use it to create backup, sql server show error that private key is missing. I don't want to give anyone my private key. I don't want to upload it to the server. Why?

Comment: I can't answer you you don't want to upload it to the server.

Comment: The principle of the asymmetric cipher is that one side has a public key and second side has a private key.

In this case, the sql server has both keys. Then the asymmetric encryption is useless ... I don't get it.

Comment: To ask a foolish question, but how do you expect the server to decrypt it's backup, without said private key?

Comment: In practice, the number of times a backup is not even unpacked on the same server on which it was created. It will be restored elsewhere, data will be pulled out of it, and it will be passed to the destination server as a simple table, etc.
In other words, we create thousands backups per year, but if we're lucky, we don't even have to recover one. Why should thousands of backups roll somewhere in the storage unencrypted (encrypted, but anyone can decrypt them because it has a private key)

Comment: Then I go back to m,y original question; why is everyone on your server a `sysadmin`? That's the problem here.

Comment: ps: when needed, the private key will of course be uploaded to the server, the backup will be restored and the key will be deleted again

Comment: Everyone is not sysadmin. But theoretically (attacker) can somehow get database backup and private key. Which is security nonsense.
If the private key was not on the sql server, the attacker only gets a backup that is useless to him. Because it has no way to decipher it.

Comment: A Hacker would only gain access to it, if they are a `sysadmin`, exo. And if they have `sysadmin` priviledges, gaining access to the backup is the least of your concerns.

Comment: I expected this answer :-) but there are other reasons.
1) It's basically wrong. 2) I do not want the same private key for 50 different customers. Thanks to this MS property I have to make a different one for everyone. 3) Then if I want to extract the backup on my server, then I must manage 50 different keys etc ...

Comment: 4) if an attacker compromises a non-critical server, it gets a private key from it to unpack critical backups belonging to another server of the same customer